# Youtube as3 API seems not functional anymore

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube, youtube-api

I'm working with the as3 Youtube official API and I need to load the API Player in a swf file.

I've done it on several projects and everything was fine but since a few hours, all my projects are now broken.

Here's the piece of code that is crashing :

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, playerLoaded);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, playerError) ; 
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
```

An empty and not very helpful IOErrorEvent is now sent :

```
   [ErrorEvent type="onError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text=""]
```

As everything was OK yesterday, I've checked other flash sites using YoutubePlayer and they all seem damaged.

Is anyone running through the same issue? Youtube doesn't say anything about this.

To complete my request, even loading http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3 in my browser throws an debug player error!
Thanks !

Comment: We have troubles with js API too:
http://s.ytimg.com/yts/swfbin/apiplayer3-vflm4I60t.swf 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I've got the exact same 404 error. Looks like Google broke something !

Comment: I've twitted them about the issue: https://twitter.com/mbektimirov/status/274082457047945216 
Do the same to make them see it ASAP.

Comment: Apologies; things are back to normal now, as folks have noted. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3000

Answer (score 4):

Youtube is currently down, and has been for about an hour now:
http://downrightnow.com/youtube#refresh

Comment: Thanks for the link! Looks like there's not much to do except waiting. Come on Google! I'm on a release day!  ^^