# YouTube chromeless player not loading

Tags: youtube-api

Suddenly today the YouTube chromeless player stopped working . I can't load it anymore, "onError" event is triggered immediately after the player is loaded. Event.data should contain the error code, but there is no data anymore. The stack from where the event comes is:

```
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at com.google.youtube.application::SwfProxy/onLoaderError()
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622387/youtube-as3-api-seems-not-functional-anymore

Comment: Apologies; things are back to normal now, as folks have noted: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3000